# Using sprites for list images

Tags: image, list, background, sprite

I want to use sprites for list background images. I have seen a few methods of doing this, but they all require set height and/or widths for each list item. The dimensions of each list item I have will be different so I can't set that.

Ideally, I want to be able to have a sprite image set up, then choose to display only part of it e.g. 50px by 50px in the top left corner, but I want the content of the list element to be able to be any height and width. I am also trying to ensure that the sprite image always remains centered in comparison to the list text next to it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps you should indicate for which GUI framework you need that? Can be HTML, GWT, Swing, JavaFX, GTK+, Qt, Win32 and the list goes on...

Comment: Apologies, I am coding in HTML5.